# Difference between ".append" and predefined lists when using the Worksheet.update method

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am trying to use the Worksheet.update method to update the values in the cells A2, A3, A4 of a sheet with the following code:

```
sheet = USER_SPREADSHEET.worksheet('sheet_name')
values = []
for i in range(1,4):
    values.append([str(i)])

sheet.update('A2:A4', [values])
```

I am getting the following error:

> APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'Invalid values[1][0]: list_value {\n  values {\n    string_value: "1"\n  }\n}\n', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}

I can fix it by using the following alternative, but I have no idea what is causing the difference:

```
sheet = USER_SPREADSHEET.worksheet('sheet_name')
value1 = '1'
value2 = '2'
value3 = '3'

sheet.update('A2:A4', [[value1],[value2],[value3]])
```

The above works and I won't get an error, but it's not useful for what I need.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this answer?

#### Modification points:

In your following script, `values` is `[['1'], ['2'], ['3']]`.

```
values = []
for i in range(1,4):
    values.append([str(i)])
```

But, when `sheet.update('A2:A4', [values])` is run, `[values]` is `[[['1'], ['2'], ['3']]]`. I think that this is the reason of your issue. So if you want to use the upper script, please modify as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
sheet = USER_SPREADSHEET.worksheet('sheet_name')
values = []
for i in range(1,4):
    values.append([str(i)])

sheet.update('A2:A4', values)  # Modified
```

#### Reference:

- [Updating Cells](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html?highlight=update#updating-cells)

Comment: Thanks!! Can't believe I missed it  :(